# Guzzlehttp complaining about headers when multipart is being used in POST request

Tags: php, guzzle

When I try to upload a file using guzzlehttp 6:

```
$response = $this->client->post($uri, [
        'multipart'    => [
            [
                'name'     => 'File-Name',
                'filename' => $document->name,
                //'Mime-Type' => $document->mime_type,
                'contents' => fopen( $file->getPathname(), 'r' ),
                'headers'  => [
                    'Access-Token' => $this->token,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ] );
```

I end up getting an error when it tries to create the headers:

```
There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testSend
ErrorException: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

/home/vagrant/intakes/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/MessageTrait.php:151
/home/vagrant/intakes/vendor/guzzlehttp/psr7/src/Request.php:53
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: You sure $this->token is actually a string? Try dumping it out.

Comment: yes, thanks for that, but I have var_dump() the array before passing it to the ->post() function just to sanity check. It is actually choking on the fact that the multipart key is an array of arrays. But the docs clearly show that it needs to be an array of arrays.

Comment: That theory is easy to check, take out the headers key.

Comment: I actually looked at messagetrait file, and figured out its choking on the multipart, it never even makes it to the header key.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Your exact request executes with the same structure and the params set to strings. http://pastebin.com/CpYd9Ap9

Comment: thanks for your help. i redownloaded guzzle and now its working :(, I'm not sure why, but all your code examples were correct

Comment: hah, all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$response = $this->client->post($uri, [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name' => 'File-Name',
            'filename' => $document->name,
            'contents' => fopen( $file->getPathname(), 'r' ),
        ],
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Access-Token' => $this->token,
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Why does this work if the docs show that the header key is inside the multipart array? http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart